# Adding the replaceAll method to the ActionScript String class

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop, actionscript

I need some help in adding the replace all functionality into my Flex project. I would prefer doing this in a way that is as natural as possible.

What I want to achieve is to be able to run this code (with the Flex compiler) `"aabbaaba".replaceAll("b","c")` and get `"aaccaaca"`. Also I want to chain `replaceAll` calls.
*Note: I won't be actually replacing `b`s with `c`s, but various string that will not be known at coding time!*

What I don't want:
1. Use regular expressions with the global flag. The tokens to replace are determined ad run time and transforming them into a regular expression isn't straight forward.
2. Use the `StringUtil.replace` method. It's a static method and chaining is ugly.
3. Chain `split` and `join`. Because it may be confusing for others when reading the code.
4. Disable strict type checking. I want to have type checking for the rest of my code.

---

Here is what I have so far:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(replace:String, replaceWith:String):String{
    return this.split(replace).join(replaceWith);
}
```

And can be called like this:

```
"aababacaaccb"["replaceAll"]("b", "c")["replaceAll"]("c", "a");
```

---

Also, are there any recommendations against extending objects through the prototype? **I will also accept an answer that has strong arguments against extending the String object through the prototype.**

Thank you,
Alin

Comment: It would be nice if the people who down-vote would justify their action in order for me to be able improve the question. Thank you.

Comment: wtf?  you don't want to use regex?  what's the point even of doing string search/replace at all then?  You're replacing a string.  Use a string function.  It's not hard to use a variable in a regex .........

Comment: @Daniel You probably don't understand the question. Or didn't read it with enough attention. What I want to do is have what `StringUtil.replace` does, but directly as a method on my String object. I don't have a pattern, I just have a string that I want replaced. There are a lot of ways to do this, but I wanted something *clean* (like a method on Strings) or as clean as possible (like what 9re or Juan Pablo Califano suggested).

Comment: @Daniel Also you're not being coherent. I'm not referring to you bad English (which is strange because your profile states that you're from New York), but to the fact that you're contradicting yourself. For example: "you don't want to use regex?" vs. "You're replacing a string. Use a string function.".

Comment: Well you've seemed to answer your own question.  You're stating you want to replace, but you don't want to use a regex, nor join, nor split, nor StringUtil.replace, nor type checking.  wtf.  StringUtil.prototype.replaceAll = function(r:String, w:String):String { return this.replace(new RegExp(r, 'g'), w); )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got all the technical answers possible. I will elaborate in what I think is the best way to approach this language-wise.

Prototypes are not recommended in an OOP language such as AS3 (mostly because they defy encapsulation). You imply that you don't want something "confusing to others" (in relation to split.join); well, prototypes in AS3 are very confusing. 
Just as an example of this, a prototype declaration can be done from anywhere in your code, and as such is not obvious where it should reside. If "others" encounter "foo".replaceAll() in your code, it's not at all obvious where one can find that method and check what it really does.

A static function amends this and is pretty straight forward. Sure, you need an extra argument, and you can't really chain properly, but is this such a bad thing?

If you need performance, split.join is the way to go. I would bet good money that more AS3 devs know about split.join than the use of prototypes.

On the other hand, I think the most semantic and pragmatic way would be to use the own language method (hence my previous answer). You are trying to replace all needles in a string with another string in AS3, and for that the language has the String::replace method with the global flag. I'm pretty sure there is a way to easily parse and use any string in regexp.

I concur that in some cases a helper method (like replaceAll) could be necessary, but I would strongly encourage you to not use prototypes, and instead use a more standard way, like StringUtil.replace.

Comment: You're probably right with not using prototypes and I'll accept the answer for this. As for converting strings to regex equivalents that match exactly those strings, doing so would mean calling a static function on each of the replace tokens and I think that would be equivalent to other solutions posted here. What I wanted to find out with this question was if you can, and it's OK to, add functionality to an existing object type. It seems that the answer is: No. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 7):

The second answer is this:

write the wrapper class StringEx for String and you can define replaceAll to be chained like this

```
public function replaceAll(replace:String, replaceWith:String):StringEx {
   string = string.replace(new RegExp(replace, 'g'), replaceWith);
   return this;
}
```

by providing toString() you can easily change StringEx object into String

```
var result:String = "" + new StringEx("aaccaaca").replaceAll('b', 'c').replaceAll('c', 'a');
```

you can get full-version here: [OOP way of prototype extension - wonderfl build flash online](http://wonderfl.net/c/uILO)

Comment: This may be an alternative because you only need to wrap once, but I'm hoping for a prototype solution, or at least and answer that proves that what I want can't or shouldn't be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

> What I don't want:
>   1. Use regular expressions with the global flag

Why not? for simple string replacements is quite straight forward and performant:

```
"aababacaaccb".replace(/b/g, "c");
```

or if you prefer:

```
var needle:String="b";
"aababacaaccb".replace(new RegExp(needle,"g"), "c");
```

I wouldn't recommend using prototype for this, it's not very OOP nor standard... it feels too hacky for such a simple operation.

Comment: You probably didn't understand that I used `a`, `b` and `c` just to illustrate what I want. I didn't think it was necessary to say it. I want to be able to replace any string with any string. I edited the question.

Comment: Also you can't do `RegExp(needle,"g")` to convert a string in the regular expression that finds it (because of special regex symbols). Your answer is the worst so far, you didn't even try. I don't understand why anyone would up-vote it...

Comment: You are being a bit too condescending for my taste... you are right though, it's not that straight forward for any string, but I'm sure you could work that out (I would use split.join BTW)...

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to meet the 4 requirements you posted. But I think if that your main goal is replacing various tokens in one go (what you wanted to achieve with chaining calls) while being able to use any string as a token, you can try something like this:

```
public class StringUtil {
    public static function replaceAll(source:String,map:Object):String {
        for(var replaceToken:String in map) {
            source = source.split(replaceToken).join(map[replaceToken]);
        }
        return source;
    }
}

var str:String = "a1ccca111a";

str = StringUtil.replaceAll(str,{
    'a' : 'b',
    '1' : '2'
});
trace(str);
```

There's one caveat to keep in mind. With an Object object, the order is not guaranteed. In most cases, this isn't important, but if in your case it is, you could use an Array instead, and in each slot store both the token and its replacement (as an Object, for instance).

Comment: Interesting approach. "I can't think of a way to meet the 4 requirements you posted." You're saying this because literally you can't think of a way, or do you really think that adding `replaceAll` to the String object can't be done?

Comment: @Alin. Well, I meant that I can't find a way myself. And probably there isn't one (but maybe someone finds one, who knows). If you go the prototype route, you lose type-checking as you know. For all the code that uses this method; maybe there's a way to avoid this for "the rest of your code", but that'll sure be involved (if possible).

Comment: (cont) Extending String is not possible because the class is final, so using object instances (for method chaining and such) will require extra boiler-plate (you can have some kind of wrapper, but it cannot be used were a String is required; this is where I think you'll get most of the boiler-plate). So I think having a utility static method is the most simple, direct and intuitive option given the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

`"aabbaaba".split('b').join('c')` returns 'aaccaaca'

UPD: 
i wonder why it's unacceptable for you (however it doesn't support regexp): it works pretty fast (checked it in severe loops) and does exactly what you want.

and also there's a couple of solutions that's not mentioned in your blacklist (btw static function is better then messing with prototype - imho):

- you can extend String class with only `replaceAll` method and `super()` call. instances of this class will return `true` if you check `(myStringInstance is String)`
- and another solution: create a wrapper instead of extending: a class that will store a string for you providing additional functionality (though i can't imagine one for a string) and maybe making some of its' properties read-only. or it might have just a getter and setter for one

Comment: That's what he (whyever) don't want to use: *"I don't want: 3. Chain split and join"*

Comment: "btw static function is better then messing with prototype" - Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @splash I don't want split+join because it's not obvious what the combination does. It's obvious to me because I know how `StringUtil.replace` is implemented, but probably not for some else that will be reading my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers for you. The first would be what you want. But I recommend the second.

enabling prototypes in flex is very easy and can be done by setting flex-config

ReplaceAllTest.as

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    public class ReplaceAllTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function ReplaceAllTest() 
        {
            var tf:TextField = new TextField;
            String.prototype.replaceAll = function(replace:String, replaceWith:String):String{
                return this.split(replace).join(replaceWith);
            }
            // now the strict mode is off compiler does NOT warn the following code
            tf.text = "aababacaaccb".replaceAll("b", "c")
                                    .replaceAll("c", "a");
            addChild(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

ReplaceAllTest-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<flex-config>
    <compiler>
       <as3>false</as3>
       <es>true</es>
       <strict>false</strict>
    </compiler>
    <static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>true</static-link-runtime-shared-libraries>
</flex-config>
```

I still discourage this way, because enabling prototyping and turning off strict mode will slow down your code.

Comment: What did I say about strict type checking? I don't want that. I know how to do it, but I want it active for the rest of my code.

Comment: oh, sorry! I made a mistake. but compiler.es must be set with compiler.strict false:  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_14.html

Comment: @Alin Purcaru. I think you are being a bit too pushy considering that you are asking other people to help *you* to solve a *your* problem (and that they are trying to help you without getting anything from you in return).

Comment: @Juan I know I am and I apologize for it, but that's a character problem, not a programming one. I don't think there's (yet) a stack exchange site that addresses this issue :). I guess I became frustrated when I saw answers that did exactly what I specifically said I don't want. As for the problem part I went with the `[]` access before I posted the question. So you can't really say I need to have a problem solved quickly, but rather I would like to hear some competent opinions from other programmers that tackled this issue.

Comment: @Alin. Ok, I just wanted to mention that being nice doesn't hurt (even if you find the given answer unsatisfactory). Anyway, I'm posting a possible option.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this is what I came up with which can do any regular string.

```
    public static function replaceAll(p_string:String, p_search:String, p_replaceWith:String):String{

    //Dummy Control
        if(p_string == null)
            return '';

    //Iterates through the string from right to left so we don't go over what we are changing.
        var index:int = p_string.lastIndexOf(p_search);
        while(index != -1){

        //Splits the string at the index
            p_string = p_string.slice(0, index) + p_replaceWith + p_string.slice(index+p_search.length);

        //Attempts to find the next index
            index = p_string.lastIndexOf(p_search, index-1);//We -1 so we always move down the line
        }

    //Returns the modified p_string
        return p_string;
    }
```