# How to change an specific letter in string using charAt in as2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, flash-8

I have a key like this:

72ea6c148e5fa2f92abbefb86387dbd31cda8581

And now I want to change for example every 'a' of my key to 'd'.
So far I've written this code which can find every 'a' in my string.

```
for(var i = key.length; i > 0; i--){
        var eachLetter = (key.charAt((i - 1)));
        switch (eachLetter){
            case 'a':
                trace('the letter is: a');
                //key = key.charAt(i) = 'd';// this is what I'm looking for.
                break;
        }
```

but unfortunately I don't know how to change my specific letters to something else.
what should I do now!?
AS2 solutions are welcome!

Comment: From little search on google:
[String.replace() method for ActionScript2](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/as/stringreplace-method-for-actionscript2),
or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085566/adding-the-replaceall-method-to-the-actionscript-string-class)

Comment: I have seen it once but I haven't realized that this is the exact thing that I was looking for thank you.